# Is it possible to use regular expressions to match url's on $urlRouterProvider?

Tags: angularjs, regex, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use a regex expression to match all strings that don't start with **"/pt/"** or **"/en/"** in my routing config. They may or may not have additional text.

So I came up with this:

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('^(?!/(pt|en)/).*', function ($injector, $location) {
    const path = $location.path();
    $location.path('/pt' + path !== '' ? path : '/').replace();
});
```

Unfortunately this throws the error:`Invalid parameter name '.' in pattern '^(?!/(pt|en)/).*'`

What is the right way to use regular expressions in this scenario?

**EDIT**

I've changed the expression from `'{(?!\/(pt|en)\/).*}'` to `'^(?!/(pt|en)/).*'` based on Bohemian response. But the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`when` method does not have the `$injector and $location` services.use `rule()` instead,

Change the regex to `/^(?!\/(pt|en)).*/` to meet your requirement.

[Check the regexp here](https://regex101.com/r/aM40ml/1)

**rule() for custom url handling**

**Parameters**:

handler Function A function that takes in the `$injector` and `$location` services as arguments. You are responsible for returning a valid path as a string.

```
app.config(function ($urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {
           //what this function returns will be set as the $location.url
            var path = $location.path(), normalized = path.toLowerCase();
            if ('/pt.asd'.match(/^(?!\/(pt|en)).*/) == undefined) {
                // this starts with /pt or /en
                // $location.replace().path(normalized);
            }
            else
            {
              // this does not starts with /pt or /en
              // do some thing
            }
      });
})
```

[Reference you are looking for](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#rule-for-custom-url-handling)